# Searching through a webpage using iMacros / Javascript

Tags: javascript, macros, imacros

I am a newbie, don't know too much, but I've wasted so many hours on this and couldn't come up with a solution and I don't think this question has been posted already.

What I was trying to do is something very simple: I wanted to create a macro with iMacros that is able to go through a webpage, search for a certain word and if the word is found, click on a button. Else, refresh the page and start again.

I realized that there is no easy way to use if/else on iMacros, so that I'll need to add this with Javascript.
Still, my major problem is found in the macro. Basically, if I use the extract option on iMacros, it will only skim through the HTML code of the page, if I understand it correctly. This means that it will need a certain TYPE. The problem is that this webpage I am looking to skim through does update time after time but does not show these new "results" in the HTML code. I think it uses some kind of Javascript or php, not showing the text I want to find in the HTML code. How do I still program iMacros to simply search through the "visible" text on the page (in a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> kind of way)?

The macro I had implemented in my .js file that is responsible for extracting looks like this:

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*Text* EXTRACT=TXT
```

In this example I try and search for the word [...]Text[...]
If I try and use the wildcard `TYPE=*` it simply does not work.

So: Is there a way to search on a page and not only the HTML code with iMacros? How would I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your js-script you may try like so:

```
var txt = window.document.body.innerHTML;
if (txt.match(/Text/)) {
    // do something if true
} else {
    // do something if false
};
```

Here's a similar way for iim-macros:

```
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"(Text)" EXTRACT=$1
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
' do something according to the !EXTRACT text
```

Finally, you can record a click on the text and find out a certain 'TYPE', 'TAG' and 'ATTR' which the macro needs.